# "Wrong number of arguments" error when trying to click on JavaStaticText object in QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am facing an issue clicking on a JavaStaticText object in QTP while testing a Java application. I have added the objects to my object repository and named the JavaStaticText object "DEPLOY":

Here is my script :

```
Set Main = JavaWindow("MainScreen")
If Main.Exist Then
    Main.JavaButton("d").Click
Else
    print "Console is not present"
End If
Main.JavaStaticText("DEPLOY").Click
```

The script is throwing the following error at the last statement:

> Wrong Number of Arguments or Invalid Property Assignment

I am out of ideas as to why this error is thrown!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the UFT help, clicking on JavaStaticText requires that you supply X and Y coordinates. Assuming all your identifiers are correct, you can try something like:

```
Main.JavaStaticText("DEPLOY").Click 1, 1
```

... or 0, 0, or whatever you find appropriate and reliable for the given object.

Comment: Thanks Xiaofu indeed it was the issue.